# got ORA-01843 when I try to insert date & time to Oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql, ora-01843

I have A anb B in String format

A = 14/01/2007

B = 22:10:39

I try to insert date and time:

```
SQL = "insert into MyTbl(Tdate,Ttime) value ('" + Convert.ToDateTime(A) + "','" + Convert.ToDateTime(B) + "')";
```

i got ORA-01843 error, what I can do ?

thank's in advance

Comment: what does the variable SQL contain, after the assignment shown ?

Comment: Also, what datatypes are Tdate and Ttime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the month, try:

TO_DATE(A, 'DD/MM/YYYY')

Answer (score 8):

Don't use raw SQL to insert values. Use a parameterized query instead. Parse your strings into .NET `DateTime` (or `DateTimeOffset`) and `TimeSpan` values in the normal way, and then use something like:

```
string sql = "insert into MyTbl(Tdate,Ttime) values (:date, :time)";
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, connection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("date", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("time", OracleType.IntervalDayToSecond).Value = time;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

(Obviously adjust for the types of your actual fields.)

Comment: +1 for bind variables!  Also, it's silly to store date and time in two separate fields, as was mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.aspx), it looks like OracleCommand is obsolete now.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Oracle doesn't have a time-only field.

You're trying to insert a time-only field into a datetime.  My guess is that the CLR is turning B into 00/00/00 22:10:39, which isn't a valid oracle date.  For example:

```
SQL> select to_date('00/00/00', 'MM/DD/YY') from dual;
select to_date('00/00/00', 'MM/DD/YY') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Either way, Convert.ToDateTime(B) probably isn't returning the right thing.

Also, this:

```
"insert into MyTbl(Tdate,Ttime) value ("
```

should be this:

```
"insert into MyTbl(Tdate,Ttime) values ("
```

...but I'm guessing that's just a typo here.

Answer (score 1):

However i tried Jon method, it didnt work for me for date also time. So i found this method for datetime. Maybe that helps someone in next future too.

```
OracleParameter oPrm;
oPrm = cmd.CreateParameter();
oPrm.ParameterName = ":myDate";
oPrm.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date;
oPrm.Value = DateTime.Now;  //for date
cmd.Parameters.Add(oPrm);
```